# When I use EF in ASP.NET an error occurs: some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my code

```
((userIds.Count() > 0) ? userIds.Contains(x.OptionCode.ToString()) : true) &&
```

Error occurs near count

Comment: Your code is incomplete. And have you tried to reduce nesting of your query? For example, split in several queries with using of `ToList()` or `FirstOfDefault()`

Comment: Post some more code (but not too much!) so we can understand what's going on. Posting the stacktrace can also help.